# Android Keytool Issue

Tags: java, android, keytool

When I want to get md5 with keytool for the google maps api.I have same error

My Error:

Illegal error: bulal2m

My code:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -alias arabamı bulalım -keystore "c:\key.keystore"

My alias name: arabamı bulalım

My Keystore File:key.keystore

I think the error about "ı" character and space but ı dont know how can i fix

Thank you

Comment: share more and exact log details about Illegal error: bulal2m

Comment: Copy past the full error. And maybe try to quote the alias if it has a space in it. Something like: `-alias "arabamı bulalım"`.

Comment: I tried with this format keytool -list -alias "arabamı bulalım" -keystore "c:\key.keystore" and asked a password ,I entered password result it give me just SHA1 key :/ how can I get md5

Comment: ok for the md5 ı used jre6 and it solved :)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -list -alias "arabamı bulalım" -keystore "c:\key.keystore"

Thank you all my friend